# Why is 'have difficulties' incorrect?

Tags: grammar, collocation

> But it is far enough away that early explorers had difficulty/difficulties finding it.

What should I choose completing the exam task?

There is the answer 'difficulty' in the keys but the authors do not give any explanations. Why 'difficulties' is incorrect if it is?

Answer (score 1):

As I remember, '**had difficulties**' refers to a specific amount of difficulties one had to face, whereas '**had difficulty**' implies that one simply found it difficult.
So I believe that both are correct.

Comment: But context is everything: in this case it seems that the *singular* difficulty in finding it arises from the distance.

Comment: Or that it was so far away that they had to overcome a number of difficulties in addition to the mere distance.